# How to execute multiple goroutines in parallel without a Deadlock

Tags: go, parallel-processing, waitgroup

So I have been trying to run mutliple goroutines in parallel using a WaitGroup. Whatever I try I always end up with a "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan time.Duration)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, v := range []time.Duration{5, 1} {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            wait(v, ch)
        }()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}

func wait(seconds time.Duration, c chan time.Duration) {
    time.Sleep(seconds * time.Second)
    c <- seconds
}
```

However this results in a deadlock and I can't figure out why.

I have been trying to read the values after the WaitGroup with the following code:

```
    close(ch)

    for v := range ch {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
```

However it seems it wouldn't even reach this part.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the worker channel after all the workers are done. You are closing it immediately from the main goroutine.

So do this:

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
}()
```

Also your wait function already takes a `time.Duration` so really it should be in the real time at that point & not multiplied by `time.Second`. if you want to pass in units of seconds, consider changing the input type to `int` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems withe the code:

1. You must close the channel only after all go-routines have finished
2. The value of v is being lost during the iteration

In go, the for loop will reuse v, so all go-routines will have the same value on the wait call.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan time.Duration)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, v := range []time.Duration{5, 1} {
        wg.Add(1)
        v := v // <- this

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            wait(v, ch)
        }()
    }

    go func() { // Close the channel only after go-routines finish
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    for v := range ch { // Will loop until channel is closed
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}

func wait(seconds time.Duration, c chan time.Duration) {
    time.Sleep(seconds * time.Second)
    c <- seconds
}
```